# Vyatta upgrade in Softlayer

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

If a customer purchased two Vyatta devices separately, is it possible the two devices can be configured HA using a ticket afterward ? Suppose a customer purchased the same specification device within the same vlan configuration.

Answer (score 0):

what I know is that you can ugrade your Vyatta server to HA via portal, in that case you only need to pick out one server to upgrade and delete the another one.